# A c# windows service which can accept parameters

Tags: c#, windows-services

Greetings !

Is it possible to create windows service (In visual studio 2008), that can accept input parameters. If yes, Is it possible to call that specific method as when required? I have created a basic windows service but don't know whether I can pass parameters to it.

I know I can invoke method in specific intervals based on timer. But is it possible to invoke this method, when a call comes from an external program.

Any helpful information regarding these would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Sebastian

Answer (score 2):

The ServiceController.Start() method has an overload that takes an array of strings for parameters. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9c38b683.aspx

I would suggest looking into other communication mechanisms, such as WCF though.  More crude solutions involve writing files to shared disk space, or the registry, I wouldn't suggest either, though have seen both in production systems in the past.

Answer (score 1):

On the `OnStart()` method, you recieve a `string[]` arguments. These are parameters that can come from console start method. You also could add some keys on the `AppSettings` of your configuration file `app.config`, and read it inside your code.

```
protected string FirstArg { get; set; }
protected string SecondArg { get; set; }

// read from configuration file
protected string ConfigArgument { get { return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["key"]; } }

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    base.OnStart(args);

    // read from console
    FirstArg= args[0];
    SecondArg = args[1];
    //read more arguments
}
```

You also, could use registry to add keys.

Comment: Thanks, Felipe. I understand this point. Can I create any other method , other than "OnStart" to receive parameters & how I can invoke that method as & when required?

Comment: No, if you do not pass arguments for the windows service, the `args` will come null, you chould check it before using. The methods `OnStart(string[] args)` and `OnStop` comes from `ServiceBase` class, that's the reason you cannot have more than one.